# Joomla custom fields type url file - upload?

Tags: custom-field, joomla-3.7, file-upload

I am trying to add a simple file upload field type to the com_contact using Joomla's custom fields.

I see there is a 'URL scheme File' type but I couldn't figure out how to get that to work as a file upload field.

Anyone out there know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Same here, I wanted each user to be able to upload their own gallery, still looking.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found to this is to use JCE (Joomla Content Editor) a third party text editor. When you  have JCE installed it intercepts the media manager call and displays the JCE media manager instead, which can see and understand PDFs.

It's possible other 3rd party editors also have this feature. There's currently no way to modify the built-in media manager to support non image formats in the limited version that the media field loads (without hacking the plugin)

Answer (score 1):

The field you want to use doesn't work like that.

Media file type only permits to open the joomla media controller D:, but not to make an upload...

My solution for this was to make a custom module to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but as the problem still exists...

The only solution that I have found is [Advanced Custom Fields Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-custom-fields/) developed by Tassos Marinos.

It is a collection of pre-made custom fields that allows you to drag-n-drop any type of file.

Answer (score -1):

> You can use the media type field

[image]

Enjoy coding!

Comment: The 'media' field allows pdf uploads, however once uploaded the pdf does not show up because 'media' is supposed to be used for images only. Is there another solution for this? Pasted as a comment for @Nfleming

Comment: @TryHarder try installing JCE and using JCE media manager maybe?